# How to snap a graphic to a vector basemap layer

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, layers, snapping

I'm using the Sketch Wdget in a map for drawing graphics.
Is it possible to snap the drawings (polygons for example) to the roads that are part of the vector tile layer i'm using as a base map?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to snap to Vector Tile Layers right now. The types of layers you can snap to are defined in the `type` of the [`layer` property of FeatureSnappingLayerSource](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-interactive-snapping-FeatureSnappingLayerSource.html#layer):

- FeatureLayer
- GraphicsLayer
- GeoJSONLayer
- CSVLayer
- WFSLayer